# In vTiger 6.5: Which table stores the products that belongs to a quotes?

Tags: mysql, sql, vtiger, vtigercrm

I need to know which table acts as an intermediary to achieve the many-to-many relationship between these entities.

I know that the table that stores the products is `vtiger_products` and that the one that keeps the quotes is `vtiger_quotes` but I do not know which table relates both, so my query is incomplete.

So...

```
SELECT * FROM vtiger_quotes
INNER JOIN vtiger_products INNER JOIN table_relates_both
ON vtiger_quotes.quoteid = table_relates_both.quoteid
AND vtiger_products.productid = table_relates_both.productid
WHERE vtiger_quotes.potentialid = ?
```

What's the real name of `table_relates_both`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vtiger_inventoryproductrel` is the intermediary table between `vtiger_quotes` and `vtiger_products`

Below is the structure of `vtiger_inventoryproductrel` where `id` column act as a foreign key of `Quotes`, `Opportunity`, `Invoice` etc

[image]

If you want to fetch Quotes related to particular Opportunity then you need to execute below query:

```
SELECT {your required field goes here} FROM vtiger_inventoryproductrel INNER JOIN vtiger_quotes 
    ON vtiger_quotes.quoteid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id 
    WHERE vtiger_quotes.potentialid = $potential_id
```

Also note that:

> vtiger_crmentity - This is core table in which an entry is added for
>   all entity type records. This stores meta information like record id,
>   record owner id, last modified by user id, created time, modified time
>   and description.

Answer (score 2):

the table name is vtiger_inventoryproductrel